# Sharepoint 2010 powershell applywebtemplate returns error

Tags: powershell, support

I want to create a site from site templates. I use this code:

```
1 $MainWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sitecollection"
2 $SiteTemplates = $MainWeb.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033)
3 $SiteTemplate = $SiteTemplates | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "SolutionTitle"}
4 $SubWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sitecollection/subsite"
5 $SubWeb.ApplyWebTemplate($SiteTemplate.Name)
6 $SubWeb.Dispose()
```

On line 5 powershell writes error

> "Exception calling 'ApplyWebTemplate' with "1" argument(s): 'The
>   system cannot find the file specified. (`Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002`)'"

When I apply template through site it works, but it is not working with powershell scripting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is belong to sharepoint stackexchang

Comment: You may need to copy the web template from the source site collection to the destination site collection.

Comment: Web template is copied to the destination site collection and activated. I get the value in the $SiteTemplate property.